# Удалить определенную строку в SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot

**Как удалить определенную строку (message_id) в SQLite при этом отфильтровать по user_id пользователя (чтобы пользователь не мог удалить чужие записи пользователей)?**

Создание таблицы

```
"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_statistics(
                request_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                user_id INTEGER,
                username TEXT,
                full_name TEXT,
                activity TEXT,
                message_id INTEGER,
                desc TEXT,
                point INTEGER,
                datetime TEXT DEFAULT (datetime('now', 'localtime')))"""
```

Удаляет определенную строку message_id (может подобрать message_id другого пользователя)

```
sql = """DELETE FROM user_statistics WHERE message_id = ?"""
```

Удаляет последнюю строку пользователя

```
sql = """DELETE FROM user_statistics WHERE request_id IN (SELECT request_id FROM (SELECT * FROM user_statistics where user_id = ?) as tmp ORDER BY request_id DESC LIMIT 1)"""
```

Comment: o_O `WHERE message_id = ? AND user_id = ?`

Comment: @Akina Спасибо.